# Is it justified to say that $\mathbb{R}$ is the splitting field of $x^2-1$ over $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, splitting-field

In Gallian's textbook, he defines a splitting field as follows:

> **Definition.** Let $E$ be an extension field of $F$ and let $f(x) \in F[x]$. We say that $f(x)$ *splits* in $E$ if $f(x)$ can be factored as a product of linear factors in $E[x]$. We call $E$ a *splitting field for $f(x)$ over $F$* if $f(x)$ splits in $E$ but in no proper subfield of $E$.

Take, for example, $x^2-1 \in \mathbb{R}[x]$. This splits over $\mathbb R$ as well as over $\mathbb Q,$ a proper subfield of $\mathbb R.$ Is it justified, then, to say $\mathbb R$ is a splitting field of $x^2-1$ over $\mathbb R$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $E$ is defined to be an extension of $F$. The definition should really state "no proper subfield of $E$ which contains $F$", because the whole discussion depends on having a constant ground field over which you are working.

Then your statement is OK (as it should be) because $\mathbb Q$ does not contain $\mathbb R$.

Comment: So, user12345 is right, and Gallion's definition is incomplete.

Comment: From now on I'm not trying to remember the numbers, just calling all those guys user12345.  If they want to be remembered, they should choose a user name.